# Transposing coordinates from PDF map onto satellite image

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I have a map in a PDF file with boundaries that I want to plot onto a satellite image.

I have made a screenshot, saved it as tiff and imported it as a R`raster` object.
Using `click` I have outlined the boundaries which I can now plot onto the raster object.

My goal is to convert the `data.frame` with x and y coordinates to a spatial object (`sf` or `sp`) and plot it onto a satellite image.

The problem is the projection: How do I convert my relative positions to a projection that matches that of my satellite image?

Comment: Do you know the "ground" location of any points in your image and do you know what projection type was used to draw it (eg lat-long, azimuthal, conical etc) that might distort it from being a regular grid in lat-long aligned north?

Comment: @Spacedman A late reaction, sorry. Yes, I know the original projection (UTM Zone 37), projection (Transverse Mercator), Spheroid Clarke 1880 (modified).

Comment: You didn't answer the first part of my comment: do you know the coordinates in any global coordinate system (UTM37 will prob be best) of points on your map? Click on those, then you have a set of {ground-truth x,y} coords and matching {image pixel x,y} coords. Write a function that maps one to the other and apply to your polygon. This is called "georeferencing". Usually you'd georeference your image first and then you can click your polygon directly into map coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! the "georeferencing" was the magic word. There is a wizard for it in [QGIS](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html).